# How to prevent a Sharepoint 2010 application from Globally Deploying?

Tags: 2010, central-administration

I have a Sharepoint 2010 application that consists of Sharepoint application pages and donot contain any web parts. So when I deploy the wsp of the application from the central administration the application will be globally deployed. I want avoid this and deploy the application on to a particular site. How do I accomplish this?